# Why does my Javascript loop only run once?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
var board = ''
for (i=1;i<5;i++){
  for (i=1;i<9;i++){
    if (i%2 == 0){
      board += "#";
    }
    else{
      board += "O";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"
  for (i=0;i<8;i++){
    if (i%2 == 0){
      board += "#";
    }
    else{
      board += "O";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"
}
console.log(board);
```

When I try to run this code, the output is

```
O#O#O#O#
#O#O#O#O
```

The intended output is

```
O#O#O#O#
#O#O#O#O
O#O#O#O#
#O#O#O#O
O#O#O#O#
#O#O#O#O
O#O#O#O#
#O#O#O#O
```

I tried adding a `console.log(i)` right after the first for statement and it only returns "1", meaning the loop only runs once.
Why is this happening?

*Edit: When I wrap the two inner for loops in a function and call that instead, it works as intended

Comment: Hint: you have 2 loops, both using `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are reusing the same variable **i** in differents loops sentences, so the inner loops are mofiying the value of this variable.

For example. Below I use different variable names.

```js
var board = ''
// Main loop. This loop has two inner loops that writes a pair of lines in every iteration: the odd lines and pair lines.
// Note that the declared variable 'j' will be a available in the scope of this loop and any inner loop.
// Be aware that the variable 'j' will be used in this scope,
// but any modification (like reusing in another loop) will modify the variable value of 'j'.
// For this reason another variable are declared in the inner loops.
for (var j=1;j<5;j++){

  // The first inner loop add the characters of the odd lines. 
  // To not modify the variable 'j' this loop declares another variable 'i'.
  // This 'i' variable will be used for the columns of the odd lines.
  for (var i=1;i<9;i++){    
    if (i%2 == 0){      
      board += "#";
    }
    else{      
      board += "O";
    }
  }

  board += "\n"

  // The second inner loop add the characters of the pair lines.
  // To not modify the variable 'j' this loop declares another variable 'k'.
  // This 'k' variable will be used for the columns of the pair lines.
  for (var k=0;k<8;k++){
    if (k%2 == 0){
      board += "#";
    }
    else{
      board += "O";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"
}
console.log(board);
```

Comment: Perhaps its better if you can add helpful comments to your code. Will benefit the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You're

- using the same variable name for each of your loops: `i`
- not using block scope for those iteration variables with `let`

So all references to `i` in your code refer to the same binding.

At the end of the second inner loop - after `for (i=0;i<8;i++){` - `i` is 8. Then, the outer loop:

```
for (i=1;i<5;i++){
```

sees that `i` is not less than 5, so it stops.

Use a different variable name for each loop (eg `i`, `j`, and `k`), and declare your variables with `let`. Either will solve it, but implementing *both* is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks! That never crossed my mind! Solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

```
var board = ''
for (j=1;i<5;i++){
  for (i=1;i<9;i++){
    if (i%2 == 0){
      board += "#";
    }
    else{
      board += "O";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"
  for (i=0;i<8;i++){
    if (i%2 == 0){
      board += "#";
    }
    else{
      board += "O";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"
}
console.log(board);
```

There's two loops, both index's "i".
change one to 'j'

Comment: Perhaps you can add additional comments within the code to benefit the reader in general, as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried experimenting with the code, and this is what I got:**

```
var board = ''
for (i1=0;i1<4;i1++){
  for (i2=0;i2<8;i2++){
    if (i2%2 == 0){
      board += "#";
    }
    else{
      board += "O";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"
  for (i3=0;i3<8;i3++){
    if (i3%2 == 0){
      board += "#";
    }
    else{
      board += "O";
    }
  }
  board += "\n"
}
console.log(board);
```

Gives me:

```
#O#O#O#O
#O#O#O#O
#O#O#O#O
#O#O#O#O
#O#O#O#O
#O#O#O#O
#O#O#O#O
#O#O#O#O
```

The problem was that the same variable (i) was getting reused, meaning that each loop resets the variable. Instead, I added numbers after the initial i.